# How do you configure tomcat to bind to a single ip address (localhost) instead of all addresses?

Tags: tomcat

How do you configure tomcat to bind to a single ip address (localhost) instead of all addresses?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Several connectors are configured, and each connector has an optional "address" attribute where you can set the IP address.

1. Edit `tomcat/conf/server.xml`.
2. Specify a bind address for that connector:

   ```
   <Connector 
       port="8080" 
       protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
       address="127.0.0.1"
       connectionTimeout="20000" 
       redirectPort="8443" 
     />
   ```

Comment: In addition to **bind(2)** to a single address, you can also bind to more addresses by using multiple `Connector` elements. https://access.redhat.com/solutions/873953

Comment: I am getting same issue can you pl check my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75752438/6854117)?

Answer (score 13):

it's well documented here:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TOMCAT/Connectors#Connectors-Q6

*How do I bind to a specific ip address?* - *"Each Connector element allows an address property. See the HTTP Connector docs or the AJP Connector docs"*. And HTTP Connectors docs:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html

Standard Implementation -> address

*"For servers with more than one IP address, this attribute specifies which address will be used for listening on the specified port. By default, this port will be used on all IP addresses associated with the server."*

Comment: I am getting same issue can you pl check my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75752438/6854117)?

Answer (score 3):

It may be worth mentioning that running tomcat as a non root user (which you should be doing) will prevent you from using a port below 1024 on *nix. If you want to use TC as a standalone server -- as its performance no longer requires it to be fronted by Apache or the like -- you'll want to bind to port 80 along with whatever IP address you're specifying.

You can do this by using IPTABLES to redirect port 80 to 8080.

Comment: Your answer should be a comment. It does not provide a resolve for changing the `I.P.` Tomcat binds to.

Comment: Anyone running TC on linux is going to run into the port issue above.

Comment: I run tomcat on several distros... never witnessed your assertion... the accepted answer is correct.

Comment: Yeah, because you incorrectly put it behind apache or nginx.

Comment: Then you run your TC with a port above 1024 -- not a real site. Enjoy your tin plated internet sheriffs badge

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107049/discussion-between-hal50000-and-eddie-b).

Comment: I am getting same issue can you pl check my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75752438/6854117)?