# Login Check in Server Side

Tags: android, server-side

I would like know how to implement the Login Check example by comparing the `username` and `password` on `Server-side` using `Web-Services` in Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Complete Example for Authentication is [Here](http://wowjava.wordpress.com/2011/01/16/login-application-for-android/)

Comment: it was a good example my dear friend....but i still has little problem and that too i will tell you tommorow..thanks a lot

Comment: I am not able to access the webservice which is kept on my local PC's Apache server..can you give a tutorial for that...providing the url that we would use for our local host...i am unable to connect the server at all..please help me..
thanking you in advance..

Comment: i think you have problem with url

Comment: you have to hit a proper url to get proper response

Comment: Suppose..i have a php file(check.php) that returns 1 or 0 according to the username and password then how should i call that file...which url should be provided here..
response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("whichurl??",postParameters);

Should it be like

"http://localhost/haresh/check.php"........???

Comment: Exactly the same url "localhost/haresh/check.php" and parameters are username and password

Comment: Yes Ajay...i have done exactly that you told above...but it gives an error that 
    org.apache.http.conn.
    HttpHostConnectException:Connection to http://localhost refused

Comment: Andriod emulator is separate virtual machine by itself. If we provide localhost/127.0.0.1 as a hostname, then emulator will try to search url within its environment. To avoid this problem, we need to provide the ipaddress of local machine.
Pls note that machine name as a hostname will also give problem.

Comment: there is post which helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617/how-do-you-configure-tomcat-to-bind-to-a-single-ip-address-localhost-instead-o for above comment's work

Comment: Hey Ajay...i have done it...we should use the ip address that we get in cmd by ipconfig....i m able to pass the data to the php file...from their i insert it into the database of the server...

But the problem goes on Extending...
I return 1 from that php file...when i print the return value that i get in the android TextView by setText()..i get the all html syntaxs..but not the return value 1....Now how would i know that the user is authenticated or not in the java file ..??
And thankyou so much for your time...regards...buddy

Comment: I have done it like this.....
response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://192.168.1.134/haresh/check.php", postParameters);

Answer (score 0):

Use  `HttpPost`method to check login. This will make the login secured.

Answer (score 0):

you can also check out Parse.io , the service will handle most of the server-side for you, depending on what you actually want to do.