# Android: client side/web services programing

Tags: android, web-services, wamp, client-side

I'm searching for a simple example for my following problem. I'm having a server side with some web services, placed on a `WAMP` server on my laptop. In my Android project, I need to use these web sevices using a client side programing.

What is the best & simple way to do that? (All the examples I saw didn't worked to me or wasn't simple enghuf in order to understand what is going on there....).

Comment: See this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256647/login-check-in-server-side

Comment: I've tried it,exception is occure when trying using "CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost". Any idea what is the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some tutorials/resources:

1. [How to connect Android with PHP, MySQL](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)
2. [Android Login and Registration with PHP, MySQL and SQLite](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/)