# tomcat 7 change localhost to ip address/hostname

Tags: java, windows, unix, tomcat, tomcat7

I have deployed tomcat 7 on unix server. Application is working properly in its internal text mode browser which is elinks.

My server ip is 190.0.0.1 and hostname is test123. In elink i entered the URL `http://localhost:9999/Test`, then the application is working properly.

But whenever i tried to access the application hitting URL `http://190.0.0.1:9999/Test`, than it is not working. I checked the logs there is no error message in it.

May be some configuration issue i have to change but dont know which?

Comment: Is `190.0.0.1` an address that was officially obtained or just an address you gave to the server for testing purposes you're probably experiencing routing issues.

Comment: Binding to a specific adress can be done in the server.xml see [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617/how-do-you-configure-tomcat-to-bind-to-a-single-ip-address-localhost-instead-o). localhost normally refers to the loopback device 127.0.0.1 . Usually all physical devices will be bound too. But maybe there is something wrong with you network configuration. Try the server.xml with your adress.

Answer (score 0):

Please issue hostname -i in your unix box to get the ip address of your machine. Example:

```
[ssivan@wsapp403p.prod.ch4 conf]$ hostname -i
10.236.55.42
```

Then you can try with that ip address. Example:

```
http://10.236.55.42:9999/Test
```

Comment: hi sarath i gave hostname -i

Comment: Can you check your server.xml?