# Tomcat and IIS on the same port

Tags: iis-7, tomcat7

I have a server with 2 IP address, each address serves one web application that run on HTTPS.
Currently one of the web app runs on port 443 using IIS, while the other one runs on port 8443 on tomcat.

My goal would be something like this:

```
https://firstdomain.com => this should be served by the IIS server
https://seconddomain.com => served by Tomcat server
```

Is the above configuration possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have two IP addresses. You can bind one IP for IIS, another IP for Tomcat.

So, both sites can individually use port 443.

For example:

```
https://firstdomain.com => 192.168.1.2 => IIS
https://seconddomain.com => 192.168.1.3 => Tomcat
```

IIS IP binding

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb734869.aspx

Tomcat IP binding

[How do you configure tomcat to bind to a single ip address (localhost) instead of all addresses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617/how-do-you-configure-tomcat-to-bind-to-a-single-ip-address-localhost-instead-o)

Comment: I only can see 2 public IP address. Should I use them for the binding ? Will there be any performance issues ?

Comment: sure, if you have two network card, i think there is no performance impact.