# Tomcat 7.0 issue

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a tomcat7.0 running in a remote desktop machine say 204.34.34.45.
When I log into the remote desktop and try "`http://localhost:8080`" it is working fine.However 
`http://204.34.34.45:8080` is not working.

I am able to ping 204.34.34.45 from outside the remote desktop machine.

Do you know how can I access tomcat outside the remote desktop machine.

Comment: You say "http://204.34.34.45:8080 is not working". In what way is it not working? Are you getting an error message? What error? Is there a long delay, like it might be a timeout?

Comment: Since I have tomcat installed in the remote desktop  204.34.34.45, I expect http://204.34.34.45:8080 to work . It is getting timed out now.http://localhost:8080 works fine however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The firewall rules for that host may not allow connections to 8080.  Talk to your system administrator for details.

Also, make sure you have the correct IP bindings set up for tomcat.   It is possible to allow connections to localhost:8080, but disallow them from  204.34.34.45:8080.  See [How do you configure tomcat to bind to a single ip address (localhost) instead of all addresses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617/how-do-you-configure-tomcat-to-bind-to-a-single-ip-address-localhost-instead-o)

Comment: Thanks for your response.Is there any other options which can make the  address "http://204.34.34.45:8080" to work apart from enabling the firewall. If enabling the firewall is the only option left, do you know how to enable the firewall for that port..

Comment: Another option you could try is using a port that is not blocked by a firewall.  Typically port 80 is open, although another web server might be using that port on the same host, which would prevent you from binding to it.  As far as configuring the firewall, that is very dependent on the firewall vendor and where the firewall is installed, and is something you should work with the sys admins to fix.