# localhost:8080/lio/ works great in my apachtomcat. but when i put <my ip>:8080/lio/ i get error

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat

`localhost:8080/lio/` works great in my apache tomcat, but when I use`<my ip>106.5x.xx.xx:8080/lio/` I get this error:

```
The connection has timed out

The server at 106.5x.xx.xx is taking too long to respond.

    The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
    If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
    If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.
```

Comment: How do you got your IP?

Comment: It is might be duplicate of the followings . [**LNIK**][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617/how-do-you-configure-tomcat-to-bind-to-a-single-ip-address-localhost-instead-o

Comment: i get my ip from whatsmyip.com

Comment: no. its diffrent question

Comment: @user3564100 There is your problem. That is the IP of your router not your PC.

Comment: oh. how to get ip of my pc?

Comment: @user3564100 added answer

Comment: my pc ip address worked :) thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments you said you used whatsmyip.com for your IP adress. That is your router public IP adress and not from your PC. To get the IP from your PC do following

on Windows:

```
ipconfig
```

on Linux(needs root privileges):

```
ifconfig
```

Of course you can only access your tomcat from your local network this way. If you want to be able to access your PC from the internet you have to set up port-forwarding on your router if it is supported.

Comment: give me details of portforwarding

Comment: @user3564100 I can't. You have to consult the specific manual for the router you have. Not every router supports it either.

Comment: like i said above. Read the manual of your router maybe it supports port-forwarding then you could use the public IP of your router.

Comment: my router supports port forwarding. can you give me example how to do?

Comment: I don't know how it works for your router since it is different for everyone. If it is not accurately descriped in the manual you can ask a question on http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/