# Localhost vs 127.0.0.1 in Spring Framework

Tags: java, android, spring

I am attempting to connect a spring rest service to a client which is an android device.

I have followed this tutorial on creating my service: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/
Which by default runs the Spring Service on port 8080.

My issue is that on localhost:8080/test I get a correct output from my service but on 127.0.0.1:8080/test I get 404 Not found.

Is there any reason for this? I specifically need to connect to 127.0.0.1 for debugging purposes with an android emulator.

Thank you.

Comment: Try `nslookup localhost`. You should get `127.0.0.1`; if you get something else, use that.

Comment: I did get 127.0.0.1 which doesn't really solve my problem.

Comment: Assuming you're using the default Tomcat with Spring see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23953385/2970947).

Comment: I ended up specifying -Dserver-address=127.0.0.1 and -Dserver-port=1320 in VM options and that seemed to work. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This could be because Java 7+ is using IPv6 as the default instead of IPv4. Thus **localhost** resolves into **:::1** instead of **127.0.0.1**.

Try the following:

Just pass -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true to java VM options.

If this works you can make it permanent by setting _JAVA_OPTIONS on Linux:

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
```

You can place the above line inside /etc/profile or /etc/profile.d/java.sh (by creating the file java.sh)