# 127.0.0.1 vs localhost - Spring Security Login issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am new to Spring and Spring Security. I've managed to create a simple application that lets the user login and logout. For testing purposes, I ran the server on my machine on port 8081. The authentication seems to work fine when I try to access the site through `127.0.0.1:8081`, but it doesn't work when I try to access the site from `localhost:8081`

The security configuration is as follows

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/html/**", "/jsp/**").denyAll()
                .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .permitAll()
                .loginPage("/loginPage")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard")
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");
}
```

Debug output for `127.0.0.1:8081` when hitting a POST request for login is as follows

```
org.hibernate.SQL                        : select userdata0_.uid as uid1_0_, userdata0_.email as email2_0_, userdata0_.first_name as first_na3_0_, userdata0_.last_name as last_nam4_0_, userdata0_.password as password5_0_ from user_data userdata0_ where userdata0_.email=?
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/dashboard", parameters={}
s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.server.VController#getDashboard()
o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8]
o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : View name '/jsp/dashboard.jsp', model {}
o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : Forwarding to [/jsp/dashboard.jsp]
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
```

But the debug output for `localhost:8081` for the same request is

```
org.hibernate.SQL                        : select userdata0_.uid as uid1_0_, userdata0_.email as email2_0_, userdata0_.first_name as first_na3_0_, userdata0_.last_name as last_nam4_0_, userdata0_.password as password5_0_ from user_data userdata0_ where userdata0_.email=?
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/loginPage", parameters={}
s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.server.VController#getLoginPage()
o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8]
o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : View name '/html/loginpage.html', model {}
o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : Forwarding to [/html/loginpage.html]
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "FORWARD" dispatch for GET "/html/loginpage.html", parameters={}
o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/", "/"]
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "FORWARD" dispatch, status 200
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
```

The request seems to loop back to the login page even if the credentials are correct. I cannot seem to figure out why this behaves so.

A related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35470838/localhost-vs-127-0-0-1-in-spring-framework) seems to mention the loopback address and localhost (issue is vice versa). But in my case, the problem is with authentication. Unauthenticated pages seem to work fine.

**Edit 1:** Weird enough, the issue seems to occur only with Chrome. The authentication works fine in Firefox/Safari.

The request headers sent by Firefox are

```
=== MimeHeaders ===
host = localhost:8081
user-agent = Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0
accept = text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
accept-language = en-US,en;q=0.5
accept-encoding = gzip, deflate
content-type = application/x-www-form-urlencoded
content-length = 53
origin = http://localhost:8081
connection = keep-alive
referer = http://localhost:8081/loginPage
cookie = zscookcsr=dc59fe1e-35a8-4633-8fae-fb2ef0962a00; JSESSIONID=BB5487443E0CE64F4FE889C3BA51320A
upgrade-insecure-requests = 1
```

On the other hand, the request headers sent by Chrome are

```
=== MimeHeaders ===
host = localhost:8081
connection = keep-alive
content-length = 53
cache-control = max-age=0
upgrade-insecure-requests = 1
origin = http://localhost:8081
content-type = application/x-www-form-urlencoded
user-agent = Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36
accept = text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
sec-fetch-site = same-origin
sec-fetch-mode = navigate
sec-fetch-user = ?1
sec-fetch-dest = document
referer = http://localhost:8081/loginPage
accept-encoding = gzip, deflate, br
accept-language = en-US,en;q=0.9
cookie = ztcookcsr=e74ce2f0-b7d7-4f09-a1a7-0834c599e32d; Idea-7029dd45=276a767c-c715-4838-9756-45bea2bdafcc; Idea-407559eb=da31aa72-ff54-488a-b154-e909efb275c3
```

Before I try to clear cookies/data for the site, I would like to know why this behaves so.

Comment: what's at `localhost:8081`, if you see the same page or response then it's not a problem with your hostname resolution

Comment: @夢のの夢 It's the all the same pages when not authenticated. The problem occurs only when trying to login.