# Grails 3 - Configure embedded Tomcat bind address

Tags: tomcat, grails, grails-3.0, grails-3.1

I am running my Grails 3.1.3 application as standalone JAR using the embedded Tomcat servlet container and start the WAR by the following command:

```
java -jar -server -Dserver.host=127.0.0.1 -Dserver.port=50000 -Dgrails.env=prod -Xmx768M myApp.war
```

By using the `server.port` I successfully managed to set the Tomcat listening port to `50000`. But the `server.host` does not seem to set Tomcats bind address to `127.0.0.1` since it is visible from the Internet.

Is there a way to successfully set the bind address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23946369/how-to-configure-embedded-tomcat-integrated-with-spring-to-listen-requests-to-ip). Simply use the property `server.address` to set the bind address.

Answer (score 1):

In application.yml, i set my urls and ports as

```
    grails.serverURL: 'http://localhost:8080/appname'
    server:
      port: 8080
      contextPath: '/appname'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't think that will work. `grails.serverURL` does not set Tomcats bind address. It is used for link generation. But according to the Spring Boot documentation my answer above solves the problem.