# Spring Boot: Error in API access : Failed to connect to <domainName>

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I have created a REST API example in Eclipse using Spring Boot. 
When I access API  using `http://localhost:8080/getInfo` then it works, but if I am accessing the same API from external client using IP address `http://<IP address>:8080/getInfo` then it gives error - Failed to connect to  
How to access API using IP address OR Domain Name?

Comment: how you start java app ?

Comment: Are you trying to access your REST service through a machine which is connected to the network where your server machine is in? if not can you explain the exact scenario you are trying to achieve?

Comment: From the external client, can you successfully ping your IP ?

Comment: Are you running your server in local machine or cloud?

Comment: Which application is your external client

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure embedded Tomcat integrated with Spring to listen requests to IP address, besides localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23946369/how-to-configure-embedded-tomcat-integrated-with-spring-to-listen-requests-to-ip)

Comment: Can you please add what you have tried? Have you checked your firewall? Can you ping the host from an external client? What OS are you running?

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan I run the application using command - mvn spring-boot:run

Comment: @Damith yes. machine is in the same network. And I can also ping my IP from that machine.

Comment: @Nithin Running on local machine, in same network

Comment: can you provide the exact error that you are getting?

Comment: Getting error "Failed to connect to <IP Address>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to specify different server address other than localhost or any other server configuration like port, error controller or timeout settings, you can do it using server default properties in application.properties. Spring will automatically load embedded tomcat configurations from the application.properties file.
For different server address use.

```
server.address= # Network address to which the server should bind.
```

In you application.properties.

For other server configurations, have a look at : [Spring Common Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)