# Not able to connect to docker image with a spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, containers

Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8 
ADD target/docker-spring-boot.jar docker-spring-boot.jar
EXPOSE 8085
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","docker-spring-boot.jar"]
```

command to build docker

```
docker build -f Dockerfile -t docker-spring-boot .
```

spring boot jar location below .

```
target/docker-spring-boot.jar
```

command to run docker

```
docker run -p 8085:8085 docker-spring-boot
```

The application works normally without a docker. Not able to run the application on docker.

Error:

```
This site can’t be reached
```

docker run logs

```
 E:\micorservices_samples\docker-spring-boot\docker-springbootdocker run -p 8085 :8085 docker-spring-boot

   .   ____          _            __ _ _  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __
 _ \ \ \ \ ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / / 
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/  :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.4.RELEASE)

 2019-04-07 18:29:47.944  INFO 1 --- [           main]
 c.r.d.DockerSpringbootAppl ication        : Starting
 DockerSpringbootApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on 352ac4d 12009 with PID
 1 (/docker-spring-boot.jar started by root in /) 2019-04-07
 18:29:47.970  INFO 1 --- [main] c.r.d.DockerSpringbootAppl
 ication        : No active profile set, falling back to default
 profiles: defaul t 2019-04-07 18:29:54.302  INFO 1 --- [          
 main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.To mcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized
 with port(s): 8085 (http) 2019-04-07 18:29:54.463  INFO 1 --- [       
 main] o.apache.catalina.core.Sta ndardService   : Starting service
 [Tomcat] 2019-04-07 18:29:54.464  INFO 1 --- [           main]
 org.apache.catalina.core.S tandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine:
 [Apache Tomcat/9.0.17] 2019-04-07 18:29:54.854  INFO 1 --- [          
 main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring
 embedded WebApplicationContext 2019-04-07 18:29:54.855  INFO 1 --- [  
 main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoa der            : Root
 WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 6539 ms 2019-04-07
 18:29:55.859  INFO 1 --- [main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoo
 lTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService
 'applicationTaskExecutor' 2019-04-07 18:29:56.691  INFO 1 --- [       
 main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.To mcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on
 port(s): 8085 (http) with context path '' 2019-04-07 18:29:56.705 
 INFO 1 --- [main] c.r.d.DockerSpringbootAppl ication       
 : Started DockerSpringbootApplication in 10.902 seconds (JVM runn ing
 for 12.566)



 C:\Users\Mabeldocker logs -f 20026c6c7602

   .   ____          _            __ _ _  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __
 _ \ \ \ \ ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / / 
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/  :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.4.RELEASE)

 2019-04-07 18:51:23.381  INFO 1 --- [           main]
 c.r.d.DockerSpringbootAppl ication        : Starting
 DockerSpringbootApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on 20026c6 c7602 with PID
 1 (/dsb.jar started by root in /) 2019-04-07 18:51:23.403  INFO 1 ---
 [           main] c.r.d.DockerSpringbootAppl ication        : No
 active profile set, falling back to default profiles: defaul t
 2019-04-07 18:51:29.434  INFO 1 --- [main]
 o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.To mcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with
 port(s): 8085 (http) 2019-04-07 18:51:29.608  INFO 1 --- [          
 main] o.apache.catalina.core.Sta ndardService   : Starting service
 [Tomcat] 2019-04-07 18:51:29.613  INFO 1 --- [           main]
 org.apache.catalina.core.S tandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine:
 [Apache Tomcat/9.0.17] 2019-04-07 18:51:30.012  INFO 1 --- [          
 main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring
 embedded WebApplicationContext 2019-04-07 18:51:30.014  INFO 1 --- [  
 main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoa der            : Root
 WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 6275 ms 2019-04-07
 18:51:31.038  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoo
 lTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService
 'applicationTaskExecutor' 2019-04-07 18:51:31.879  INFO 1 --- [       
 main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.To mcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on
 port(s): 8085 (http) with context path '' 2019-04-07 18:51:31.895 
 INFO 1 --- [           main] c.r.d.DockerSpringbootAppl ication       
 : Started DockerSpringbootApplication in 10.631 seconds (JVM runn ing
 for 12.241)
```

Github link
https://github.com/robert07ravikumar/spring-boot-docker

[image]

Comment: can you please provide some more logging output. as per logs your app is running but when you hit API what is happening?

Comment: start your app with `docker run -d -p 8085:8085 image-name` and then post output of `docker logs -f container_id`

Comment: added docker logs

Comment: How are you running docker (Mac, Windows, Linux host, docker toolbox)? And include the value of `echo $DOCKER_HOST`.

Comment: $ echo $DOCKER_HOST
tcp://192.168.99.100:2376 .Running docker on windows 7and docker toolbox.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The URLs I was trying was `localhost` , `127.0.0.1` , `0.0.0.0`, etc .

The application worked once I ran the docker host URL:

`http://192.168.99.100:8085/rest/docker/hello1`

Answer (score 8):

Your application seems fine, and it seems you can access it *from within the container* with localhost as per your comment:

```
root@a6664e1d3b83:/# curl localhost:8085/rest/docker/hello1 
Greetings
root@a6664e1d3b83:/# . I am able to get the response from the curl url
```

It's probably because **Spring Boot will bind to localhost by default (127.0.0.1)**. You need to add the following properties to bind to all host (or specify which IP on which to bind):

```
server.address=0.0.0.0 # Bind all
```

In your `application.properties`

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23946369/how-to-configure-embedded-tomcat-integrated-with-spring-to-listen-requests-to-ip) and the [Spring Boot Common Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)

Answer (score 1):

I am able to run spring boot app with docker as below dockerfile :

```
FROM maven:3-alpine AS build-project
ADD . ./docker-spring-boot
WORKDIR /docker-spring-boot
RUN mvn clean install

FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
EXPOSE 8080
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-project ./docker-spring-boot/target/docker-spring-boot-*.jar ./docker-spring-boot.jar
CMD ["java", "-jar", "docker-spring-boot.jar"]
```

For run command:

```
docker build -t docker-spring-boot .
docker run -it -d -p 8080:8080 docker-spring-boot
```

You need to replace **docker-spring-boot** with your jar file name located in target after build.

Comment: please check my code and find the mistake I am making

Comment: My jar name is docker-spring-boot.jar

Comment: Can you get into your container and send a curl request to verify that your application correctly run inside container?
`docker exec -it containerId /bin/bash && curl http://localhost:8085`

Comment: root@a6664e1d3b83:/# curl http://localhost:8085/rest/docker/hello1
Greetingsroot@a6664e1d3b83:/#   . I am able to get the response from the curl url  .  @RestController

Comment: It looks your application returns response as you see "Greeting". Did you try to send a request from your host machine? What error do you see?

Comment: response from host machine   This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Answer (score 1):

Its work for me. Here I am using docker Quick start terminal (Oracle Virtual Box) . I tried to find what is container IP by using 'docker-machine ip' command in quick start terminal. It gave me ip like 192.168.99.100. So then in browser I entered url like http://192.168.99.100:8080/hello1 and it gave me expected result. So first try to get the ip by using docker-machine ip command.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works well on any **UNIX** machine, the problem is related to the Docker network for the Windows version. By default when running docker use **bridge** network if no other is specified but in Windows the Docker network works in a different way, you can check the link [here](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/204#issuecomment-258638899) for more detail about the issue. This is a know bug but hopefully will be address some day by the Docker team.

Elton Stoneman in his blog will also give you a better explanation about this issue, see the following [link](https://blog.sixeyed.com/published-ports-on-windows-containers-dont-do-loopback/).

Answer (score 0):

in the hopes that this might help someone avoid what i just endured:  realized that i had updated my application.properties / yml with `server.port: 8049` but my docker-compose file mapped ports `- '8049:8080'`.  worked fine in the IDE but attempting to telnet to the docker container connected then immediately closed the connection.  i'll take to the grave the number of hours i wasted trying to track this down...