# How can I properly self-host my Spring Boot app on my computer?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, networking

I can't connect remotely to my SB app that I want to self-host

**Introduction**

I made a Spring Boot app with a 'my-sql' container that I want to share outside my home network to test it with some friends. The app works locally but I want to use it outside my network.

I have never, ever, deployed an app and I have little knowledge on this matter and I want to do it properly to avoid problems that I won't be able to handle myself.

**What have I done so far**

- I tried opening the 8080 port on the firewall for any connection
- I added my public ip in the application.properties with port 8080
- Used 0.0.0.0 to listen to any connection to 8080 as in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23946369/how-to-configure-embedded-tomcat-integrated-with-spring-to-listen-requests-to-ip)
- Load the app to Heroku (success) and self-host the 'my-sql' (that one is another question)

**Problem**

None of these solutions above worked for me

Comment: What you are doing won't work because your network router still needs to figure out where to send incoming requests. Opening a port won't "just work". Check this article out: https://hackaday.com/2022/03/15/run-your-own-server-for-fun-and-zero-profit/ Is not spring boot but it may point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a network-related question. You will need to set up a few things first:

- Get a static IP provided by your Internet Service Provider (ISP)
- You need to configure your network gateway to forward requests to the server hosting your application