# Tomcat: change port from 8080 to 80 not working

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, digital-ocean, vps

I have a tomcat server running on DigitalOcean VPS. The `server.xml` file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />

  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />

  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />


  <GlobalNamingResources>

    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>


  <Service name="Catalina">


    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />

    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />



    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">


      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">

        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">


        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

I edited the `<Connector>` part to make the server run on port `80` instead of `8080`. Before the changes I could access the server using `IP:8080` address, but now I can't access it at all - whether I use `IP:8080` or `IP:80` or `IP`. 
I restarted my tomcat using `shutdown.sh` and `startup.sh` and restarted my droplet using `sudo reboot`, but it changed nothing.

I checked the firewall using `sudo ufw status verbose` and it gave an `inactive` status.

**EDIT**:

I tried the `shutdown.sh` -> `startup.sh` -> `sudo reboot` route again and here is the `catalina.out` since the `shutdown.sh` command:

```
28-Oct-2018 11:40:10.377 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await A valid shutdown command was received via the shutdown port. Stopping the Server instance.
28-Oct-2018 11:40:10.378 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-80"]
28-Oct-2018 11:40:10.380 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
28-Oct-2018 11:40:10.442 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service [Catalina]
28-Oct-2018 11:40:10.494 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
28-Oct-2018 11:40:10.495 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-80"]
28-Oct-2018 11:40:10.498 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-80"]
28-Oct-2018 11:40:10.498 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
28-Oct-2018 11:40:14.691 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/9.0.12
28-Oct-2018 11:40:14.697 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Sep 4 2018 22:13:41 UTC
28-Oct-2018 11:40:14.698 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         9.0.12.0
28-Oct-2018 11:40:14.698 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
28-Oct-2018 11:40:14.698 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            4.4.0-138-generic
28-Oct-2018 11:40:14.698 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
28-Oct-2018 11:40:14.698 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
28-Oct-2018 11:40:14.706 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_181-8u181-b13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1-b13
28-Oct-2018 11:40:14.706 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
28-Oct-2018 11:40:14.706 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /opt/tomcat
28-Oct-2018 11:40:14.706 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /opt/tomcat
28-Oct-2018 11:40:14.707 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
28-Oct-2018 11:40:14.707 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
28-Oct-2018 11:40:14.707 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
28-Oct-2018 11:40:14.708 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
28-Oct-2018 11:40:14.708 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
28-Oct-2018 11:40:14.708 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
28-Oct-2018 11:40:14.708 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/opt/tomcat
28-Oct-2018 11:40:14.709 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat
28-Oct-2018 11:40:14.709 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tomcat/temp
28-Oct-2018 11:40:14.709 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib]
28-Oct-2018 11:40:14.857 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-80"]
28-Oct-2018 11:40:14.887 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
28-Oct-2018 11:40:14.900 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
28-Oct-2018 11:40:14.907 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
28-Oct-2018 11:40:14.908 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 896 ms
28-Oct-2018 11:40:14.958 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
28-Oct-2018 11:40:14.962 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.12
28-Oct-2018 11:40:14.980 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/docs]
java.util.logging.ErrorManager: 4
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/tomcat/logs/manager.2018-10-28.log (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.openWriter(FileHandler.java:495)
    at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:168)
    at org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.<init>(AsyncFileHandler.java:82)
    at org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.<init>(AsyncFileHandler.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:602)
    at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:538)
    at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:336)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$3.run(LogManager.java:399)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$3.run(LogManager.java:396)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.readPrimordialConfiguration(LogManager.java:396)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.access$800(LogManager.java:145)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:345)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.ensureLogManagerInitialized(LogManager.java:338)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager(LogManager.java:378)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:448)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:502)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.<init>(DirectJDKLog.java:61)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.getInstance(DirectJDKLog.java:181)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:116)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:139)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:194)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.<clinit>(Bootstrap.java:52)
java.util.logging.ErrorManager: 4
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/tomcat/logs/host-manager.2018-10-28.log (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.openWriter(FileHandler.java:495)
    at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:168)
    at org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.<init>(AsyncFileHandler.java:82)
    at org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.<init>(AsyncFileHandler.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:602)
    at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:538)
    at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:336)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$3.run(LogManager.java:399)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$3.run(LogManager.java:396)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.readPrimordialConfiguration(LogManager.java:396)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.access$800(LogManager.java:145)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:345)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.ensureLogManagerInitialized(LogManager.java:338)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager(LogManager.java:378)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:448)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:502)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.<init>(DirectJDKLog.java:61)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.getInstance(DirectJDKLog.java:181)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:116)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:139)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:194)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.<clinit>(Bootstrap.java:52)
28-Oct-2018 11:40:31.547 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/9.0.12
28-Oct-2018 11:40:31.552 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Sep 4 2018 22:13:41 UTC
28-Oct-2018 11:40:31.552 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         9.0.12.0
28-Oct-2018 11:40:31.552 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
28-Oct-2018 11:40:31.552 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            4.4.0-138-generic
28-Oct-2018 11:40:31.553 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
28-Oct-2018 11:40:31.553 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
28-Oct-2018 11:40:31.553 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_181-8u181-b13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1-b13
28-Oct-2018 11:40:31.553 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
28-Oct-2018 11:40:31.553 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /opt/tomcat
28-Oct-2018 11:40:31.553 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /opt/tomcat
28-Oct-2018 11:40:31.553 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
28-Oct-2018 11:40:31.559 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
28-Oct-2018 11:40:31.559 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.awt.headless=true
28-Oct-2018 11:40:31.559 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom
28-Oct-2018 11:40:31.560 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
28-Oct-2018 11:40:31.560 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
28-Oct-2018 11:40:31.560 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
28-Oct-2018 11:40:31.561 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xms512M
28-Oct-2018 11:40:31.561 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx600M
28-Oct-2018 11:40:31.561 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:+UseParallelGC
28-Oct-2018 11:40:31.561 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
28-Oct-2018 11:40:31.562 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/opt/tomcat
28-Oct-2018 11:40:31.562 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat
28-Oct-2018 11:40:31.563 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tomcat/temp
28-Oct-2018 11:40:31.563 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib]
28-Oct-2018 11:40:31.727 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-80"]
28-Oct-2018 11:40:31.751 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-80]]
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:935)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:533)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:852)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:656)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:306)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:491)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.initServerSocket(NioEndpoint.java:236)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1044)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:540)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:932)
    ... 13 more

28-Oct-2018 11:40:31.753 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
28-Oct-2018 11:40:31.765 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
28-Oct-2018 11:40:31.788 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 1791 ms
28-Oct-2018 11:40:31.843 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
28-Oct-2018 11:40:31.844 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.12
28-Oct-2018 11:40:31.852 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.beforeStart Unable to create directory for deployment: [/opt/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost]
28-Oct-2018 11:40:31.858 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.open Failed to open access log file [/opt/tomcat/logs/localhost_access_log.2018-10-28.txt]
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/tomcat/logs/localhost_access_log.2018-10-28.txt (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.open(AccessLogValve.java:651)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.startInternal(AccessLogValve.java:685)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.startInternal(StandardPipeline.java:179)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:965)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:682)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)

28-Oct-2018 11:40:31.863 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/docs]
28-Oct-2018 11:40:32.472 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/docs] has finished in [608] ms
28-Oct-2018 11:40:32.472 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/host-manager]
28-Oct-2018 11:40:32.543 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/host-manager] has finished in [70] ms
28-Oct-2018 11:40:32.544 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/manager]
28-Oct-2018 11:40:32.590 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/manager] has finished in [46] ms
28-Oct-2018 11:40:32.595 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/Test]
28-Oct-2018 11:40:32.644 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/Test] has finished in [50] ms
28-Oct-2018 11:40:32.645 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/RedditDesk]
28-Oct-2018 11:40:32.681 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/RedditDesk] has finished in [36] ms
28-Oct-2018 11:40:32.681 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT]
28-Oct-2018 11:40:32.723 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [42] ms
28-Oct-2018 11:40:32.724 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/examples]
28-Oct-2018 11:40:33.158 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/examples] has finished in [434] ms
28-Oct-2018 11:40:33.165 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
28-Oct-2018 11:40:33.196 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 1408 ms
```

Comment: Which user are you running tomcat as? On linux, you need a superuser to bind to port 80

Comment: @ernest_k Root user.

Comment: Did you bind it to your IP address? Seems like it's bound to localhost. What happens when you test `localhost:80`?

Comment: @ernest_k But it isn't my localhost, isn't it? It's a remote VPS server with it's own IP address. I don't currently run any webserver on my local machine. `localhost:80` just gives me a `XAMPP` dashboard greeting. I added the `catalina.out` logs in my post.

Comment: So what I'm trying to say is that you may need to change the host config to `<Host name="<IP address here>"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">`, replacing `<IP address here>` with the IP address you're using to test

Comment: @ernest_k Thanks for the idea, I'll try it now. Though I wonder why would the `localhost` name work fine with `8080` port and not work with `80`.

Comment: @ernest_k Then `IP` path still doesn't load, but the `IP:8080` now gives a `HTTP Status 404 – Not Found Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.` error which is new.

Comment: Sorry, it's not `"name"`, it's the `address` attribute that must take the IP address. You may need to make sure that all tomcat instances are shut down

Comment: Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617/how-do-you-configure-tomcat-to-bind-to-a-single-ip-address-localhost-instead-o

Comment: @ernest_k I used to think I only have 1 instance running. Is there a way to check? I just run sudo systemctl status tomcat after shutdown and it gives: `Process: 1716 ExecStop=/opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE) Process: 1353 ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS) Main PID: 1376 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)`

Comment: It's interesting that now that I checked it, after some time after `./shutdown.sh` if I check the status again, it become `active` even if I don't run `./startup.sh`.

Comment: Have you noticed that you have this in your log: `Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
`? That suggests an exception on attempt to open the port.

Comment: @ernest_k Thanks for sticking with me. I figured it out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With help of @ernest_k I managed to find the problem. The problem was that the port was never truly changed from `8080` to `80`. It happened because although I **was** connected  as a root user to the VPS, the tomcat automatically switched to non-root user `tomcat`, because of `/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service` file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking

Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre
Environment=CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/temp/tomcat.pid
Environment=CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat
Environment=CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat
Environment='CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC'
Environment='JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom'

ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh

User=tomcat
Group=tomcat
UMask=0007
RestartSec=10
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

So I changed a `User=tomcat` to `User=root`, restarted everything and now it works fine!

Comment: It helps me out!! Thanks!! Can you please also post what caused this issue?

Answer (score 0):

port no 1 to 1023 is reserved for the system use may be because of that you are not able to change the port no to 80.

Comment: Any way to check if the port was indeed changed?

Comment: go inside the tomcat directoryTomcat 9.0_Tomcat9.0.1\backup and open server.xml   and search for <Connector port="3030" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" /> here 3030 is current port no